# Several sections of a website managed by an application using a single core?

Tags: cakephp

Is it possible to **manage different sections** (forum, blog, portfolio) an **internationalized website** (content and interface) in a **single application using the same core**.

Each section will have its own view / controller / model, all managed by a single heart.

Example:

```
/en/home 
/en/about
/en/contact
        /en/blog/
        /en/blog/article

        /en/forum/
        /en/forum/category/
        /en/forum/category/topic/
        /en/forum/category/topic/post


/fr/accueil 
/fr/a-propos
/fr/contact
        /fr/blog/
        /fr/blog/article

        /fr/forum/
        /fr/forum/categorie/
        /fr/forum/categorie/sujet/
        /fr/forum/categorie/sujet/message
```

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what `AppModel`, `AppController` and `AppHelper` are for. All plugin classes should extend from these which allows you to make global methods.

You should look at some applications built using CakePHP for more ideas, [Infinitas](http://github.com/infinitas), [Croogo](http://github.com/croogo). These both have a 'core' with 'plugins' such as what you list here.

You can do the `/en` / `/fr` bit with something like [this](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/11/28/cakephp-url-based-language-switching-for-i18n-and-l10n-internationalization-and-localization/)